# How to distribute an iOS app to a client organisation's employees?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mobile, app-store

We are a contracting company and we develop software that we provide use to clients via subscription service.

We've just built an app on iOS for the first time and are trying to figure out how to distribute it to our client's employees.

Unfortunately our client has some roadblocks and will not be getting Apple Business Manager. The client would also like to use their MDM software Citrix to manage the app. No clue how to incorporate this. So from my understanding, the only other way to distribute it is to sign the app with their ad-hoc profile and then provide a download link?

Is this correct or is there a better way to do it? I've looked at Enterprise distribution but it looks as if this method assumes the organisation distributing the app has full proprietary ownership of the application which is not the case here (we own it). Is there a way around this?

I'm learning the ropes here so not really sure what the best approach is. Would appreciate any further insight given the context I've provided.

Cheers!

Comment: They will need to sign up for Apple Business Manager. You can then make the app available to them as a custom app in App Store Connect. Ad hoc distribution won't work; you would need to add all device ids to your developer program, and you are limited to 100 devices. If anyone gets a new phone you would have to add *that* id, and you can only remove ids at the end of the year.  You could make it an unlisted app, but without Apple Business Manager, it wouldn't be distributed by the MDM.

Comment: @Paulw11 what if any organisation having more than 100 employees and they want to listed for all of them ?

Comment: Ad hoc distribution is only for development. Apps distributed using adhoc expire.  To distribute to employees without using the enterprise program you need a build reviewed and signed by Apple. Either a public App Store app, a custom app or an unlisted app. If they don't want to make the app available publicly(or it isn't suited for the App Store) and you can't use Apple Business Manager then an unlisted app may work but anyone who gets the url can install the app and it can't be managed by MDM without Apple Business Manager

Comment: @Paulw11 Is apple business manager the only way to manage the app with MDM? I have read that if we build the app with the clients profile, they can then deploy the app with MDM. Is this correct? Are there any risks to this such as IP theft?

Comment: MDMs can distribute publicly available apps without Apple Business Manager, but you don't want to make the app publicly available.  You want to make a custom app, and that needs the client to have Apple Business Manager.  Even if they gave you access to their developer program to sign the app, they would still need Apple Business Manager to "purchase" it from themselves.  If they have an enterprise program membership then they can provide you with the signing certificates you need to sign the app for them to distribute directly, but the app will need to be re-signed every 12 months.

Comment: I suggest you watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10667 and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10892 and https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304 to understand your distribution options

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks that makes sense and is in line with what I've read. With the enterprise program option. Are there any risks involved with building the app with their certs/profiles? If we go down this route, could they technically have IP ownership of the app since it was signed with their Organisation? Secondly, can enterprise program apps be distributed with MDM?

Comment: With the enterprise program they wouldn't have your source code.  You are just signing the built app with their cert.  When Apple signs your code with their cert, they don't own your IP.  Enterprise program apps can be distributed via MDM.  In fact it is painful *not to use an MDM* with enterprise apps.  Apple makes it relatively difficult to get an enterprise program membership as they have been abused by companies in the past.  There are considerably more hoops to jump through compared with ABM.  If they can't sign up for ABM they will probably not sign up for enterprise

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok thanks very much very informative :) So we'd build the app with our profile but then sign it with their certificate? They wouldn't have our source code but what would they have? Just a plain old signed IPA file? Do you by any chance have any sources on their lack of IP if we sign with it with their cert? Mostly so I can show it to my boss and maybe solve this problem we have hah! They already have an MDM setup with other apps so I'd say they already have an enterprise program.

Comment: They would have the same thing as if they downloaded an app from the App Store; A signed, compiled binary.  Remember that IP is a *legal concept*.  Even if you gave them access to your source code, that doesn't mean they can do anything with it legally.   Just because they have an MDM doesn't mean they have an Enterprise Developer program agreement.  Most organisations do not because they are expensive, painful to administer and ABM provides a simpler solution these days